# throw not working properly

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, c++11

I declared the size of the array to be 2 and I tried inserting on the 3rd array position. The insert function is supposed to throw -1 when the position > size+1(using pos-1 when assigning the element into the array) but the throw is not stopping the assignment for the 3rd array position so I am getting a segmentation fault.

```
template <class T, int N>
class person : public people<T>
{
    private:
    T a[N];
    int size;
    public:
    person();
    virtual void insert(int pos, T info);
    virtual T show(int pos);
};
template<class T, int N>
person<T,N>::person(){
    size = 0;
}
template <class T, int N>
void person<T,N>::insert(int pos, T info){
    if (pos <= 0 || pos > size+1)
        throw -1;
    a[pos-1] = info;
    ++size;
}
template <class T, int N>
T person<T,N>::show(int pos){
    if ( pos <= 0 || pos > size+1 )
            throw -1;
      return a[pos-1];
}

void putin( people<name>*& aPerson ) {//passing aPerson itself

    string first("Julia"), last("Robert");
    name temp(first, last);
    string ft("Delilah"), lt("McLuvin");
    name temp2(ft, lt);
    string fst("oooh lala"), lst("broomdat");
    name temp3(fst, lst);

    try{
    aPerson-> insert(1,temp);
    aPerson-> insert(2,temp2);
    aPerson-> insert(3,temp3);
    }
    catch(...){ cout<< "error\n";}

}


int main(){
    people<name>* aPerson = new person<name, 2>();
    putin(aPerson);
    try{
    cout << aPerson->show(1);
    cout << aPerson->show(2);
    cout << aPerson->show(3);
    }
    catch(...){ cout<< "error\n";}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The first instance of the word `throw` appears about half way through this massive, poorly-spaced piece of code you pasted up here.  Would it be possible for you to trim out all the irrelevant bits?  No one needs to read your entire project to help you figure out the error.

Comment: @nhgrif It is done good sir.

Answer (score 3):

Every time you insert something, you check size variable and later increment it. When you hit size == N, nothing happens. You just step out of array bounds, you need to consider case when size is about to get bigger than your array.

Comment: Since I'm doing a[pos-1] = info. I want to be able to insert even if size = 0

Comment: You were right the first time.  In insert(), `a[pos-1] = info;` is executed, corrupting the value of size.  On the next call to insert(), it's some giant number, and thus has a bad access.

Comment: Changed my downvote to an upvote now.  This answer pretty clearly explains the problem, I believe.

Comment: igleyy's answer is correct. I would upvote but I don't have enough reputation. Thanks for the contribution guys.

Comment: @user2972206 You may not be able to upvote, but you can accept this answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using STL? If yes better try using `vector<T>::at` secure method which will do all necessary checks for you and throw `std::out_of_range` exception when getting outside its bounds.